# How can i find a row that must have N > 1 associations as a condition avoiding N+1 queries

Tags: mysql, polymorphic-associations

Given the following table:

```
id  category_id categorizable_id  categorizable_type
66  22          67                Image
72  22          75                Image
74  15          71                Image
104 15          67                Image
126 15          113               Image
```

Now i want to select those "Images" via a left join who's category_ids are 22 ***and*** 15
My sql currently looks like this:

```
SELECT images.id FROM images 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN category_links 
    ON images.id = category_links.categorizable_id AND category_links.categorizable_type = 'Image' 
    where 
      category_links.category_id = "22" AND
      ( 
        select count(*) from category_links 
          where category_links.categorizable_id = images.id AND 
          category_links.categorizable_type = 'Image' AND 
          category_links.category_id = "15"
      )
```

How can this be rewritten eliminating the need for a subquery ?

Comment: You need images from images table and also associated categories from the above table if exists ?

Comment: you count(*) part is not clear... can you explain what you are trying to do

Comment: @Kshitij if `count(*)` is 0 the statement is false and the condition is not met.

Comment: @Sudhakar I need the images, _without duplicates_, which have N > 1 specific associated categories

Comment: @KaiKönig can you give a expected result in the above case with images table ?

Comment: @Sudhakar the query would just yield the image with the id `67` because it has category  id:15 & id:22

Comment: @KaiKönig to yeild only a single row then you can append LIMIT 1 in the where condition.

Comment: Why the LEFT JOIN? Should the image id show up even if it doesn't have all the specified categories (fields from the category_links table will be `NULL`)? So to make your problem clearer, you want **ONLY** those images which have **ALL** specified category_id's in the category_links table **AND** are of the type `'Image'`? Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do this efficiently without a subquery, but the situation has room for improvement:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT images.id, COUNT(l.categorizable_id) AS occurrences
     FROM images i
     LEFT OUTER JOIN category_links l
     ON i.id = l.categorizable_id AND l.categorizable_type = 'Image'
     WHERE l.category_id IN (15, 22)
     GROUP BY l.categorizable_id) temp
WHERE occurrences = 2;
```

The main advantage here is that it's trivially easy to configure this query: you specify which categories you are searching for with `IN(...)` and how many of these categories have to match with the `occurrences = N` test.

The above query will thus return all images which are in both categories; if `occurrences >= 1` it would return images in either category or both; etc.

You can lose the subquery if you use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` for the `occurrences` check, but this is not usually a good idea because in essence it filters the results of the subquery (as written above) row-by-row and as a consequence performance suffers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want distinct image ids then you can use distinct.

```
SELECT distinct images.id, 
COUNT(links.categorizable_id) AS occurrences
FROM images i
LEFT OUTER JOIN category_links links
ON i.id = links.categorizable_id AND links.categorizable_type = 'Image'
WHERE links.category_id IN (15, 22)
GROUP BY links.categorizable_id) temp
Having Count(links.categorizable_id) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    a.id
FROM
    images a
INNER JOIN
    category_links b ON a.id = b.categorizable_id
WHERE
    b.categorizable_type = 'Image'
    AND 
    b.category_id IN (22, 15)
GROUP BY
    a.id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 2
```